Can I use Python 2 and Python 3 using Anaconda?
This is my first question in stackoverflow.
I'm currently using Ubuntu 18.04 to build Chrome V8.
I need Python 3.8 and Python 2.7 versions, but the latter is already installed on Ubuntu, so I don't need it. But Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is installed with Python 3.6 by default, which causes problems during the V8 build process. (ninja related issues)
Therefore, to use Python 3.8, we installed Anaconda and ran the command below to configure the virtual environment.
conda create --name v8 python=2.7
If I create an environment with Anaconda(2021.04), I thought Python 3's version would stay at 3.8 which is the Python version of Anaconda, but it ran 3.6, which is the Python 3 version of the existing Ubuntu.
For your information, I also tried the update-alternates command, but the operating system itself is not working, so I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to resolve the issue of this method.
How do I fix this so I can use Python 3.8 and Python 2.7 versions at the same time?
or
Can I change link python command to python2.7(System default) on my anaconda base environment?

For the record: (1) Current versions of V8 require no Python 2.x any more. (2) Upgrading (both Ubuntu and V8) may be a better use of your time than trying to figure out how to keep old versions on life support a little while longer.

Welcome to Stack Overflow!
Python 2.x has been deprecated since ~2008, with no security updates since 2020.  Are you sure you need it?  It would probably be better to simply make the small changes to whatever script you are running to make it compatible with the latest.
Anyway, with conda you can make multiple isolated environments running different versions of python like this:
conda create --name v27 python=2.7
conda create --name v38 python=3.8
conda activate v27


+1. There was a time, a few years ago, when most of the world had already moved away from Python 2.x but some of the build-time tools that V8 relied on hadn't been migrated yet. But those times are long gone!

I solved this issue!
Add this line at the end of file.
alias python=/usr/bin/python2.7

then you can use python2.7 (default) and python 3.8(anaconda3)!

I would suggest using anaconda either exclusively or not at all.  You can isolate the different versions of python using environments.  Mixing non-ananconda and anaconda versions of python is going to invite confusion.
